# Extracting string between identifiers using regex

Tags: regex

I need to extract the string between identifiers (`[[1]] some text [[\1]]`) and each identifier needs to start and end with the same numeric value.

I have found this solution until now:
/(?<=[[([0-9])]])(.*?)(?=[[\([0-9])]])/gm

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/W8lZST/5)

Which gives the correct text, but I need to identify the numbers between the start and end identifiers.

`[[1]] abc [[\1]] [[2]] pqr [[\2]] xyz [[3]] rst [[\3]] [[5]] ijk [[\5]]`

Expected results:
`[" abc ", " pqr ", " rst ", "ijk" ]`

**xyz** should be ignored as it is not between identifiers.

I have updated my regex to look like this:
[Updated Example](https://regex101.com/r/W8lZST/6)
Please let me know if its the right way.

Comment: [`\[\[(\d+)\]\](.*?)\[\[\\\1\]\]`](https://regex101.com/r/mb4u9x/2) seems enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following regex pattern:

```
\[\[(\d+)\]\](.*?)\[\[\\1\]\]
```

The content contained inside the tags would be available as the *second* capture group.

### Demo

```
\[\[(\d+)\]\]   match an opening tag e.g. [[1]], and capture the number
(.*?)           match and capture all content inside the tags
\[\[\\1\]\]     match a closing tag (\1 represents the number)
```

Comment: In the demo, it returns a 1st string which is **abc**, I want other string as well. How would I do that?

Comment: @RoshanSuvarna You would typically do that by using your regex from a programming language (such as Python, PHP, Java, C#) which exposes an API to apply the pattern repeatedly over the entire string.  To do what you want from a regex demo would mean repeating the above pattern however many times you expect to find a match.

Answer (score 0):

This regex might do the trick:

```
\[\[(\d)\]\]\s([^\]]*)\s\[\[\\\1]\]
```

You get your strings with `\2`

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/o4R0Ni/1).